# Remove lines containing non-ASCII characters from a file in Perl

Tags: perl, file, non-ascii-characters

I have a file with aprox `12,000` lines generated every `6` hours. On some of these lines, there are non-ascii characters.

I would like to be able to run a Perl script to remove all lines that have non-ASCII characters in it.

Comment: Why is is appropriate to destroy data?

Comment: @tchrist - Not sure about OP's context, but for example when the file needs to be loaded into a software which barfs at non-ascii and the business requirements don't mind losing lines (e.g. loading partial file is better than none) but do mind mangled lines that would result from deleting or encoding non-ascii characters (e.g. file format is position based). This is a VERY realistic scenario, I have had to do it in my job.

Answer (score 6):

You can do:

```
perl -i.bak -ne 'print unless(/[^[:ascii:]]/)' file
```

---

Regex explanation for `/[^[:ascii:]]/`:

`/` start of regular expression
  `[` start of character class
  `^` make this a *negative* character class (a class that matches anything besides what is listed)
    `[:ascii:]` any ASCII character
  `]` end of character class
`/` end of regular expression

Comment: Wouldn't it be `-i'*.bak'`? EDIT: Never mind, they're equivalent

Comment: Just tried both, they create a backup file named .bak but the original file is now populated with ⨪⨪⨪扭牥› instead of readable data. EDIT: If I convert the original file from .txt to .html and run the code, it appears to work well. Why would this not work on a .txt file?

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -p
END {close STDOUT}
use 5.010;
use utf8;
use strict;
use autodie;
use warnings qw<FATAL all>;
use open qw<IN :bytes OUT :encoding(US-ASCII) :std>;
BEGIN {$SIG{__WARN__}=sub{confess}}
use sigtrap qw<stack-trace normal-signals error-signals>;
use Carp;
"disconcertingly";
```